# Select all the categories and for each category last 5 post

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 table one categories and one posts. How do I select all the categories and last 5 post from each.

I have this code so far

```
include("includes/connect.php");
$get_cats = "select * from categories";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);

while ($cats_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {
    $cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title=$cats_row['cat_title'];

    echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
    echo '<ul class="list-group ">';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item table-header"><strong>';
    echo $cat_title;
    echo '</strong><span class="badge badge-color">12</span></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';         
}
```

Structure of table categories

```
cat_id cat_title
1      sports
2      news
3      bla
4      bla
```

In post I have a categ_id.

Comment: Please show us your table structure.

Comment: also specify which sql dialect

Comment: i use Mysql with phpmyadmin

Comment: i need a box with category title and 5 post with their name with link

Comment: you want only five record from table?

Comment: last 5 yes i dont know how to make the sql

Comment: 5 posts for each category?

Comment: yes, but i need the last posts inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run your second query inside above while loop for getting category post data

```
while ($cats_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {
    $cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id'];

    $sql2="select * from post where cat_id=".$cat_id." order by id desc limit 5"; 
    $second2=mysql_query($sql2); 
    while (post_row=mysqli_fetch_array($second2)) {
        // do your stufff
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to test it i will comeback

Comment: i answer with complete code hope you give a like for future use

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [SQL join method](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) which you want to use with cat_id from two tables. Than you could either change SQL query in order to get just 5 results or you could make a counter in PHP for each category and skip the rest if you already have 5. Of course you need to take into account how much data you have there. In case you have big database, best would be to solve it with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I edit a litle bit but here is the final code:

```
    <?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");
    $get_cats = "SELECT * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);

     while ($cats_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

        $cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id'];
        $cat_title=$cats_row['cat_title'];
                echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
                echo '<ul class="list-group ">';
                echo '<li class="list-group-item table-header"><strong>';
                echo $cat_title;
                echo '</strong><span class="badge badge-color">12</span></li>';


     $sql2="SELECT * from posts_req where categ_id='$cat_id' ORDER BY post_id desc limit 5"; 
      $second2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        if (!$second2) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
             }

    while ($post_row=mysqli_fetch_array($second2)) {

                echo '<a href="#" class="list-group-item border-none fonts">'.$post_row['post_title'].'</a>';


         }

                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</div>';    

     }

    ?>
```